# How do I create 4 rows of SDL_Rects with each row being a different color?

Tags: c++, sdl2

So using a class i've created a vector and managed to make one row of SDL_rects(with collision detection and destroy on collision). But when I make a second row(and obviously 2 or more rows):
1) it doesn't make the row
2) it makes the row on top of the first row and overrides the color.

BTW this is a breakout game and i've looked through a bunch of source code but I can't find an answer.

I thought if I pass a variable called(barType) using a switch statement I can do this, but it doesn't work.

Here is part of the Bar class:

```
Bar(int xPos, int yPos,  int barType){
    x = xPos; y = yPos;
    type = barType; shown = true;
    gBar.x = x;
    gBar.y = y;
    gBar.w = 130;
    gBar.h = 20;
}
int x,y;
int type;

void show() {
    //if(shown) {
        switch(type) {
            case 0:
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 255, 0, 0, 255);
                break;
            case 1:
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0, 205, 0, 255);
                break;


        }
  //  }
}
```

I managed to do it by using images but when I use color it doesn't work.I get a "Bad access" error from Xcode.

Here is the for loop that creates the Bars:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
    for (int i =0; i < 5; ++i) {
        //if (bars.size() <=4) {
            bars.push_back(Bar(xOffset, yOffset, j));
        //}

        xOffset = xOffset + 154;
       // SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(Renderer, 204, 204, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderDrawRect(Renderer, &bars.at(i).barsRectGet());
        SDL_RenderFillRect(Renderer, &bars.at(i).barsRectGet());


    }
    xOffset = 0;
    yOffset += 20;
}
```

TLDR: I want to created 4 rows of SDL_Rect. Each row containing 4 or 5 Rects(doesn't really matter right now).And each row being a different color.

I hope I formatted this question so you guys can understand easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your issue is that you're using SDL_RenderDrawRect. If you simply set the color using SDL_SetRenderDrawColor, then call SDL_RenderFillRect, you should get exactly what you want. Here's a quick re-work of your code that should hopefully work:

Bar:

```
SDL_Rect rect;
int r,g,b;
bool shown;

Bar(int x, int y, int r, int g, int b) {
    this->rect = { x, y, 130, 20 };
    this->shown = true;
    this->r = r;
    this->g = g;
    this->b = b;
}

void show(SDL_Renderer* renderer) {
    if(this->shown) {
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, this->r, this->g, this->b, 255);
        SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, this->rect);
    }
}
```

Main Loop:

```
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 0);
SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

for (int i =0; i < 5; ++i) {
    bars.at(i).render(renderer);
}

//Update screen
SDL_RenderPresent(gRenderer);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem with that is I can't easily remove a rect once it has collision. I imagine I can make a for loop and add i to the x to offset it, but I can't think of how to "delete" one of the rects

Comment: You just don't render it? Since you are clearing the screen every update by using SDL_RenderClear(), all drawn things get removed and then re-drawn. So you just need to have a flag for whether to show it or not. Let me update my main answer with a re-work of your show and render code.

Comment: You've helped me out a lot. But if I need to access the rect how do I do this? since it's in the show function

Comment: Updated the example to generate the rectangle as a member variable.

Comment: `r = r;` and the other two won't do what you expect. both `r`'s name the parameter.

Comment: Good catch, updated to directly reference the variables with this->